# Como eu uso o Command Window do VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio

Como eu utilizo o Command Window? Nunca utilizei essa ferramenta para debugar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só para você executar alguns comandos do Visual Studio. Pode ser mais fácil que fazer algumas coisas por ele para quem está acostumado a comandos. Pode agilizar por não precisar usar o *mouse*.

Uma [lista do que dá para fazer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/reference/visual-studio-command-aliases?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). [Outros comandos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/reference/visual-studio-commands?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Obrigado e feliz natal a todos e que 2015 realizemos tudo o que necessitamos.